# Naming convention for a RESTful resource that returns a list of entities with most properties hidden?

Tags: rest

We have an endpoint, let's call it

```
/items
```

which returns a list of items. The endpoint returns all the properties on the items, and ends up returning a *lot* of data, since each item is a pretty heavy JSON object.

At the moment, I'm looking at creating a lightweight varsion of this endpoint that can be used to reduce the bandwidth, and returns only a limited number of properties (e.g. only item.Name and item.Year).

Is there a naming convention for such an endpoint?

I was thinking along the lines of

```
/lightweight-items
```

or similar.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a naming convention for such an endpoint?

Not that I've heard of. Also `/lightweight-items` implies that there are resources called 'lightweight-item', which is not true.

I suggest you add a query option to specify the data you need, something like

```
/items?properties=name,year
```

Where `name,year` are the ones you want to have retrieved

Comment: It might be nice to spell out properties if you think a human will ever read the URI.